# Google Maps Javascript API V3 scroll less responsive than simple google map embed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a store locator web app and I have a problem with the scroll. The scroll/zoom works only if I scroll really intense.

This problem is on their demo codes as well:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

But if you scroll on http://maps.google.com/ the scroll works really well.

Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: I've observed this in IE8 and maps api v3. This is due to the tiles fading in and out, as far as I can see so I sniff browsers and if my users are using IE8, I serve them up a v2 map where the scroll/zoom works much much better. As far as I know, there's no way to turn off the tile fading when zooming/panning in v3. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Adam you should def make this the answer.  Nice work.

Comment: @Adam I am using Firefox 12 on Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stated in my comment to the OP:

I've observed this in IE8 and maps api v3. This is due to the tiles fading in and out, as far as I can see so I sniff browsers and if my users are using IE8, I serve them up a v2 map where the scroll/zoom works much much better. As far as I know, there's no way to turn off the tile fading when zooming/panning in v3